# VBA EntireRow.Delete until specific Column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am using `EntireRow.Delete` to Delete some rows in my Excel Programm. It works very well!

I need a way to delete the `EntireRow` but I have to exclude some Columns at the end of that row.

Is it possible to call `EntireRow.Delete` and `exclude some Columns?` Here is my Code:

```
Dim j As Long
Dim count As Long
count = 0
Dim searchRng As Range: Set searchRng = Range("Q9:Q5000")
Dim Cell As Range

For j = searchRng.count To 1 Step -1
    If ((searchRng(j).Value < CDate(TextBoxDelete.Value)) And (searchRng(j).Value <> "")) Then
    
    count = count + 1
    
    Debug.Print ("Cell " & count & ": " & searchRng(j).Value & " txtbox: " & TextBoxDelete.Value)
     
     
'    searchRng(j).EntireRow(, -6).Delete
    
     searchRng(j).EntireRow.Delete      ' Original - works but I need to "cut off" the last columns
     
 '   searchRng(j).EntireRow.Cells(, 19).Delete                                                                             
                                                                      
    ' Debug.Print searchRng.EntireRow.Offset(, 7)
     
    End If
     
    Next j
```

I have tried to use some `Offset` and other Functions on that line but with no luck. Does anyone know how I could change it so it deletes the entire Row but keeps the columns at the back lets say from ***Column "T"*** in place and does not delete those.

Comment: You can do `Range("A" & j, "S" & j).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp`. This will delete the whole row from A:S leaving column T to end untouched. It will of course mean column T will go out of sync with ones that aren't deleted. The way around it is to `.Clear` instead of `.Delete` the cells.

Comment: Confusing question. You can either delete a row or not delete it. Do actually want to keep the entire row and just clear contents of some cells (A:S)?

Comment: So basically deleting the entireRow is good for most cases but there are cases where these is extra Data comming after Column T - therefore I need to delete everything except the part at the back. BUT it still should move the next Row 1 up so there are no Empty Cells

Comment: @Simon ah so if I want the Cells to not be out of Sync I could use your approach with Clear instead of Delete right?

Comment: Then just add an if statement. If cell in column T is not blank, then do my first comment formula, else delete entirerow.

Comment: Yes but you will have empty cells. Simply because say you delete S10. S11 will now become S10 but T11 will stay as T11 because T10 wasn't deleted. If you are not deleting the entire row, that is what will happen.

Comment: @Simon okay thanks, I get that - I guess its possible to programmaticaly solve this issue but I feel like it is a lot of work. Thanks tho!

Comment: The only way I could think of it is to move what's in column T somewhere else (for the rows to delete) then delete the entire row. Just a thought.

Comment: @Simon I just tried your code if I use it like this: searchRng("A" & j, "S" & j).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp - I get an Error that the Types dont match. If I use it like this: Range("A" & j, "S" & j).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp - it deletes every Row.

Comment: It will delete every row that meets your `If` criteria. Like I said before you can add another If statement within your current one to check if column T contains anything and if it does, then do my code, else delete the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EntireRow` as the word says is the entire row. But you can use `Resize` to cut it off at a specific column.

Try the following

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet  ' better define your sheet like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  ' get last used row in column Q so you only loop through actual data
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Set searchRng = ws.Range("Q9", "Q" & LastRow)
    
    Dim Count As Long
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = searchRng.Count To 1 Step -1
        If (searchRng(j).Value < CDate(TextBoxDelete.Value)) And (searchRng(j).Value <> "") Then
            Count = Count + 1
            
            ' clear content from column A to Q
            searchRng(j).EntireRow.Resize(ColumnSize:=19).ClearContents
            
            ' check if entire row is empty
            If searchRng(j).Offset(ColumnOffset:=ws.Columns.Count - searchRng(j).Column).End(xlToLeft).Column = 1 Then
                ' row is empty delete it
                searchRng(j).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

This

```
searchRng(j).Offset(ColumnOffset:=ws.Columns.Count - searchRng(j).Column)
```

jumps to the very last cell in that row and then uses `.End(xlToLeft)` to go left until it finds a cell with data. So if the column number is `1` that means the entire row is empty and can be deleted.

So in the example below the red cells trigger the deletion

[image]

and it ends up with

[image]

As you can see the row with `1` was cleared until column T because there is more data behind, but the row with `3` was entirely deleted because it was totally empty after clearing it from A to S.

---

\ Edit according comment

If you don't want empty cells use

```
        If (searchRng(j).Value < CDate(TextBoxDelete.Value)) And (searchRng(j).Value <> "") Then
            Count = Count + 1
            
            ' clear content from column A to Q
            searchRng(j).EntireRow.Resize(ColumnSize:=19).Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
```

Comment: Okay- Thanks that is a lot of information. The code kinda works, it deletes till the column i want it to which is good but it leaves the Cell emtpy - so it does not stay in sync. Anyway thanks I think I will try to maybe move the Part that gets cut off somewhere else so I could use my previous code. Thanks have a good day!

Comment: @yesIamFaded what do you mean by "*it does not stay in sync*"?

Comment: What I mean is that lets say the row content is deleted till the column T. Then everything behind T stays what is good - but the content of the row below should move one up, which it doesnt it stays empty. But thanks anyways I was able to move the Part somewhere esle.

Comment: Yes just using this is actually the way I want it - Thanks